# What is water displacement value for LEGO solid hulls?

Tags: piece-information, water, boat

I'm building a boat model out of LEGO and I need to decide which boat hull to use. I need the smallest that can carry 485g of load. Where can I get information about water displacement of unitary LEGO boat hulls? I can compute upper bound based on the dimensions, but I'm afraid that will be a big overestimate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the simpler problem would be to evaluate the boat hulls you could possibly find to see if any would displace 485 grams of water with enough free board to stay afloat.

Here is a list of all of the unique boat hulls I could find on bricklink that looked to me likely to hold water:

[Boat Hull Unitary 16 x 8 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28533&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2016%20x%208%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 22 x 8 x 2 1/3 (Set 6429)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71958c01&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2022%20x%208%20x%202%201/3%20(Set%206429)&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 24 x 6 x 3 with Red and White Racing Stripes Pattern on Both Sides (Stickers) - Set 4002](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bfloat1c01pb01&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2024%20x%206%20x%203%20with%20Red%20and%20White%20Racing%20Stripes%20Pattern%20on%20Both%20Sides%20(Stickers)%20-%20Set%204002&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 25 x 10 x 4 1/3 with 4010 and Police Pattern (Stickers) - Set 4010](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bfloat2c01pb02&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2025%20x%2010%20x%204%201/3%20with%204010%20and%20Police%20Pattern%20(Stickers)%20-%20Set%204010&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 28 x 8 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92710&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2028%20x%208%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 32 x 10 x 1 2/3, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71610&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2032%20x%2010%20x%201%202/3,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 32 x 12 x 4, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47859&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2032%20x%2012%20x%204,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 38 x 10 x 5 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bfloat3c01&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2038%20x%2010%20x%205%202/3&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 41 x 12 x 5 with Light Bluish Gray Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23997c01&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2041%20x%2012%20x%205%20with%20Light%20Bluish%20Gray%20Top&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 48 x 6 x 5, Base (Catamaran Half)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50821&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2048%20x%206%20x%205,%20Base%20(Catamaran%20Half)&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 51 x 12 x 6 with Side Bulges, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62791&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2051%20x%2012%20x%206%20with%20Side%20Bulges,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 51 x 12 x 6, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54100&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2051%20x%2012%20x%206,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 52 x 12 x 6 1/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bfloat4c01&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2052%20x%2012%20x%206%201/3&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 52 x 16 x 5, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30215&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2052%20x%2016%20x%205,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Boat Hull Unitary 74 x 18 x 7, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57789&name=Boat%20Hull%20Unitary%2074%20x%2018%20x%207,%20Base&category=%5BBoat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 10 x 18 Bottom Section](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13537&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%2010%20x%2018%20Bottom%20Section&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 12 x 24 Bottom Section](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54070&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%2012%20x%2024%20Bottom%20Section&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 14 x 27 Bottom Section](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54850&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%2014%20x%2027%20Bottom%20Section&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 6 x 16 with 4 x 4 Cargo Hold with Green Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=dupboat04&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%206%20x%2016%20with%204%20x%204%20Cargo%20Hold%20with%20Green%20Bottom&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 7 x 12 Bottom Section](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15576&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%207%20x%2012%20Bottom%20Section&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 8 x 15 Deck Studs with Red Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=dupboat03c01&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%208%20x%2015%20Deck%20Studs%20with%20Red%20Bottom&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Duplo, Boat Hull 8 x 17 with Police Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=dupboat05c01&name=Duplo,%20Boat%20Hull%208%20x%2017%20with%20Police%20Pattern&category=%5BDuplo,%20Boat%5D)

[Fabuland Boat Hull Large](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4787&name=Fabuland%20Boat%20Hull%20Large&category=%5BFabuland%5D)

There are over 200 variations of these parts with colors and prints. Have fun!

Comment: can you shorten that list, if there are over 200 then just send one link for all of them

Comment: How about the old buildable boat hull parts such as https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x145c01&idColor=5 + https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x146c01&idColor=5 + https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x147c01&idColor=5 ?

Comment: The OP asked for unitary hulls, not buildable ones.